# how to use explode for an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, explode

I have an array like that:

```php
array(5) {
["code"]=>
int(1)
["messageError"]=>
string(27) "La typologie est incorrecte"
["model"]=>
string(3) "lot"
["grp_regles"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
["champ"]=>
string(21) "lot_surface_habitable"
["comparaison"]=>
string(7) "between"
["valeurAttendue"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
int(16)
[1]=>
int(40)
}
}
}
}
["prerequis"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
["champ"]=>
string(6) "typ_id"
["comparaison"]=>
string(1) "="
["valeurAttendue"]=>
int(1)
}
[1]=>
array(3) {
["champ"]=>
string(22) "tranche.fus.fup.fup_id"
["comparaison"]=>
string(1) "="
["valeurAttendue"]=>
int(1)
}
}
}
```

I want to do a foreach in "prerequis":

```php
$modelRetrieve = $this->retrieveModel($model);
        $modelFind = $modelRetrieve::find($id);
        $arrayError=[];
        $query = '';
        $path = storage_path() . "/json/controle.json";
        $json = file_get_contents($path);
        foreach (json_decode($json,true) as $key => $value) {
            $test = true;
            var_dump($value);
            if($value['model'] === $model ){
            foreach ($value['prerequis'] as $key => $value2) {
                if( $test && $modelFind[$value2['champ']] == (int)$value2["valeurAttendue"] ) 
                {
                    $test = true;
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

I need in second foreach to use in `$value2['champ']` where `$value2['champ']` is "tranche.fus.fup_id. So I need to explode that to have `['tranche']['fus']['fup_id']`.
How to use explode with that ?
thanks everyone :)

Comment: currenly you have: $value2['champ'] = "tranche.fus.fup.fup_id" and you need: $value2['champ']['tranche']['fus']['fup']['fup_id'] = "" right?

Comment: i need to replace ['champ'] with ['tranche']['fus']['fup']['fup_id']. To get the value of $value2['tranche']['fus']['fup']['fup_id'] if champ contains a '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use laravel `data_get` helper:

```
data_get($value2, $value2['champ'])
```

Comment: Wow thank you, it's awesome ! i didn't know that !

Answer (score 0):

To nest the `$segment`s of the string starting with the innermost item of the result, we have to `array_reverse()` the `$segment`s so we can loop over it and wrap each iteration's result with another array level in the next iteration until we looped through the whole `$segment`s array.

```
$exploded = array_reduce(array_reverse(explode('.', $value2['champ'])), function($res, $segment) {
    return [ $segment => $res ];
}, []);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it